# Finding the "most representative" variables of a population

Tags: sampling, feature-selection, sample, survey-sampling, representative

Most polls use the so-called *quotas method* to obtain their sample. They draw candidates upon a large panel of people and add one-by-one each responding candidate to the sample unless a certain quota for this candidate is already full: e.g. if the candidate is a man and the quota for men is full, then the candidate is screened out. The quotas method ensures marginal representativity for each quota independently, but it does not ensure joint representativity. Imagine old uneducated people respond less frequently than old educated or young uneducated. Then the quota for uneducated will be mostly filled by young people, and the quota for old filled by educated people. The sample will miss the old educated people.

It would be too costly for sampling companies to aim for joint representativity of their quotas, i.e. to take as quotas the intersection of their current quota categories. This would imply too small cells and too high a number of screened-out candidates. Instead, what I am interested in is to find the appropriate quota variables, such that when used in the quotas method, the samples obtained maximize representativity. The mathematical intuition is that we are looking for the $k$ variables that are the most orthogonal among them (another plus would be that their marginal distribution is close to equiprobable to improve accuracy in finite sampling and avoid too small cells).

My bibliographic search was fruitless (maybe I used the wrong keywords?), so I am posting this question here. Any hint is welcome. Below is a sketch formalization of the problem.

Take an unordered finite set $N$, and $\mathcal V$ a finite set of variables (with values in $N$) of size $V$. Take a population of size $n$, $\Omega \subset (N^\mathcal V)^n$.

For a variable $v \in \mathcal V$ and a subpopulation $X \subset \Omega$, denote $d_v(X)$ the marginal distribution of $X$ along the variable $v$. Take $k < N$ the *number of quotas*, and $Q \subset \mathcal V$ a set of $k$ variables, called the *quotas*.

A subset $Q \subset \mathcal V$ is a *sample using the quotas $Q$ independently* (or simply a *sample using $Q$*) iff $d_v(S_Q) \sim d_v(\Omega )$ for all $v \in Q$. (Denote $\mathcal S_Q$ the set of samples using $Q$.)

Take $D_\Omega : 2^\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R $ a measure of dissimilarity between a sample and the population (e.g. the Kullback–Leibler divergence). Take $p_Q : 2^\Omega \rightarrow [0;1] $ the probability that a sample $S_Q$ is drawn given the procedure (informally) described at the beginning (in particular, $supp(p_Q)=\mathcal S_Q$).

Problem: find an algorithm that solves $$\min_{Q: \, |Q|=k}{\mathbb E_{p_Q}[D_\Omega (S_Q)]}$$

NB: I am interested in any variant of this problem: I used the expected dissimilarity in the minimization program just to fix ideas, but any analogous objective would fit (e.g. minimax, or minimize the squared dissimilarity, etc.). We could also define the probability $p_Q$ in a simpler way that what I have done, e.g. simply taking $p_Q(S) = 1/2^s$ when the sample $S$ fulfills the criterion (i.e. $S$ is a sample using $Q$ of size $s$) and $p_Q(S) = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: In the thesis of Ben Aribi (2020), the stochastic Branch & Bound algorithm may be used to solve the optimization program.

Comment: Another option if we allow for forming quotas from mixtures of variables, is to use the first components of the PCA.

Comment: We can change the problem: instead of considering $V$ variables, we consider the $N^V$ cells. If, in addition, we know for each cell the probability that people do not respond to the survey (i.e. the selection probability), we can partition $N^\cal{V}$ into $K$ groups of cells to minimize the divergence in selection probabilities between groups (or more directly, to minimize the dissimilarity between the population and the sample).